# Clear old prompt lines in bash to save scroll space

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, prompt

My terminal theme used to be like this,

[image: terminal them before]

But I thought the prompt wasted so much space. And later I got an idea that I could clean the prompt every time I ran a command. I was using bash, one of solution is to use the `preexec_invoke_exec` function.

I use the following command to clean the last prompt chars:

```
echo -ne "\033[1A\033[K\033[1A\033[K\033[31;1m$ \033[0m"
```

So that the terminal is very clean, like this,

[image]

But now my problem is, there will be problem if I want to use **multi commands in one line**, say, when I use `for i in ...`.

Here is the full version of the function in my .bashrc,

```
preexec () { echo -ne "\033[1A\033[K\033[1A\033[K\033[31;1m$ \033[0m"; echo -n "$1"; echo -ne "  \033[37;2m["; echo -n "$2"; echo -ne "]\033[0m\n"; }
preexec_invoke_exec () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # do nothing if completing
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # don't cause a preexec for $PROMPT_COMMAND
    local this_command=`history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g"`;
    local this_pwd=`pwd`; 
    preexec "$this_command" "$this_pwd"
}
trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG
```

Comment: The Glyph Lefkowitz [zsh trick](http://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) - nice!

Comment: The easy solution starts with `zsh`…

Comment: I missed your question in there...

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Well if you do `for i in $(seq 1 10); do ls; done` with his function, the output of the iterating commands gets "swallowed" so to speak. So OP wanted to sanitize the behavior while enabling that prompt. The reason why I support this is interest for awareness in the shell, usability, feedback and portability. The link I had put in my prior comment leads to the post on superuser - they went to the trouble of attributing this snippet, so it's a prototype which emulates native zsh functionality (which I think is interesting), in the form of a trap function here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `preexec_invoke_exec` has to be modified to prevent multiple executions of `preexec`. Also, modify `preexec` to take in account the actual number of lines in `$PS1` :

```
preexec () { 
    # delete old prompt; one "\e[1A\e[K" per line of $PS1
    for (( i=0, l=$(echo -e $PS1 | wc -l) ; i < l ; i++ ))
    do             
        echo -ne "\e[1A\e[K"
    done
    # replacement for prompt
    echo -ne "\e[31;1m$ \e[0m"
    echo -n "$1"
    echo -ne "  \e[37;2m["
    echo -n "$2"
    echo -e "]\e[0m"
}

preexec_invoke_exec () {
    [ -n "$DONTCLEANPROMPT" ] && return
    DONTCLEANPROMPT=x
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # do nothing if completing
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # don't cause a preexec for $PROMPT_COMMAND
    local this_command=`history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g"`;
    local this_pwd=`pwd`
    preexec "$this_command" "$this_pwd"
}

trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG

PROMPT_COMMAND='unset DONTCLEANPROMPT'
```

In order for `preexec` to be run again, `DONTCLEANPROMPT` has to be either unset or set to `''`. This is done with `PROMPT_COMMAND`, which is run just before the primary prompt is issued. Therefore `preexec` will be run once and only once for every command line.

Comment: Your solution solves the issue with the `for` loop! Thank you! There is a further inconvenience. What happens is that if you do `ls` on the command and you have the output, then you do another `ls`, you will see that the last line of the prior output gets erased... do you have an idea how to resolve that?

Comment: You are probably using a prompt with only a single line. Change the first echo in `prexec` to print `"\033[1A\033[K\033[31;1m$ \033[0m"`, that is only one `\033[1A\033[K` (move 1 line up, delete till end of line) instead of two.

Comment: Flawless! Thank you very much for your solution and taking the time to explain. This solves OP's problem and debugs the solution even further. Makes it usable for everyone! Cheers!